# Windows 8 Metro Print embedded webpage within WebView

Tags: c#, xaml, printing, microsoft-metro

In Windows 8 Metro, I want to print a webpage hosted in a WebView control.
Does the WebView control have a document that I can point to in order to invoke printing?

I want a user to be able to print a webpage by clicking the print button on the metro app that has a webpage embedded within the control.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nope. I was not able to find a solution for this.

Comment: I launched the browser as a separate app for the user to perform a print operation.